# Return array value with forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach, return

I am looking to return the name value of an array stored in another Object.

```
exports.send = function(req,res){
  req.body.items.forEach(function(item){console.log(item.name)})
}
```

Console:

```
Product 3
Product 2
```

But I don't know how to obtain those values for an HTML content which I want to send it to an email address. I tried with `return item.name` instead of `console.log(item.name)` but it doesn't work. Thanks a lot in advance! Newbie out.

Comment: You use the value where it has been delivered to you. The behavior is asynchronous, so you bring your code to the result instead of the result being brought to your code.

Comment: @squint it seems issue is not case poited

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak: Could be. Trouble is that the OP didn't explicitly show which call site needs to use the attempted return value, nor that a collection of all the `item.name` was desired. I see your accepted answer, but I'm satisfied leaving it closed until the OP provides an edit that shows more precisely the result that is needed. If the OP does actually want to create a new array of `item.name`, then an edit is needed, and the question can be closed as a duplicate of this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak: It is indeed the same. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try map  instead of foreach

```
req.body.items.map(function(item){ return item.name; })
```

Comment: Great! It works! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, good luck

Comment: This helped me as well, not sure why it had 0 votes when I got to it.